# How to update MiKTeX to utilize MiKTeX Console

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

My current installation MiKTeX 2.9 uses the old Package Manager/Settings/Update system, which doesn't seem to be functioning smoothly.  How do I safely update my system so that I have access to the newer MiKTeX Console to update my packages?

Comment: A jump over four years is never safe. You will have to decide if you want to risk it. If you have running projects think first about fallback options, e.g. try if you can compile in overleaf.

Comment: You can uninstall are reinstall, although you will need to delete the old folder (including all you packages).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Did you mean uninstall "and" reinstall, or uninstall "or" reinstall?  Is it possible to install the current version alongside my old version, or might this cause conflicts?

Comment: Sorry, **and**.  My fingers don't always type the word I'm thinking.  You might be able to install it twice using different folders, although this will probably confuse the registry.  I wouldn't try it.